# Filter Datatable records with select query using MYSQL INBUILT functions

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have seen in other posts for how to filter table records using '<' '=' conditions but I want to use mysql inbuilt functions like,

date,yearweek etc,

```
  datatable table; //--> it contains my result

   DataRow[] foutput = table.Select("YEARWEEK(Date) = 'YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)'");

    gvweeksch.DataSource = foutput;
    gvweeksch.DataBind();
```

Comment: So, what is the question? This doesn't work? Any exception or error message?

Comment: YEARWEEK--> is not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use database functions in a `DataTable` which only suports few methods. Have a look at expression-syntax in following link to see what is supported:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that a `DataTable` is just an in-memory colection which does not even know the source of the data. It's neither related nor linked with a database.

If you want to filter the table with complex conditions like the week of the year you should use `Linq-To-DataTable` instead where you have all .NET methods:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
int week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Today, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
var rowsFiltered = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                   let date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
                   where date.Year == DateTime.Today.Year 
                   && week == cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek)
                   select row;
DataTable tblFiltered = table.Clone(); // empty table with same columns
foreach (DataRow row in rowsFiltered)
    tblFiltered.ImportRow(row);
gvweeksch.DataSource = tblFiltered;
gvweeksch.DataBind();
```

Comment: getting error as "The source contains no DataRows."

Comment: @BeginnerStack1: then the filter returned no rows. I have edited my answer.